# Определить тип правила

Tags: javascript

В "terminal" может добавлять только один символ.
если "inputw1" и "inputw2" содержат несколько символов из "terminal" и из "neterminal", то в списке определяется тип правила 'type1' (например, S->aSBC, CB->CZ, bB -> bb).
если "inputw1" содержит только один символ из "neterminal", а "inputw2" содержит только символы из "terminal", то это 'type2'(например, B -> abc).
если "inputw1" содержит единственный символ из "neterminal", а "inputw2" содержит несколько символов из "terminal" и только один символ из "neterminal", то это 'type3' (например, B -> abcB, C-> Dba) В данном правиле 'inputw1' должен содержать только один символ.

```js
var term=document.getElementById('terminal').innerHTML = terminal;

var neterminal = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'];
var neterm = document.getElementById('neterminal').innerHTML = neterminal;

function pushTerminal(){
    var x = document.getElementById('newTerminal');
    var str = term.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    var str2 = neterm.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    if(str == -1 && str2== -1) {
        if(str.length !== 1){
            term.push(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
            x.innerHTML = term.join();
        }else{
            alert("error");
        }

    }else{
        alert("error");
    }
}
function determineType(str, dict, caseSensitive) {
if(!str.length){
        return false;
    } else if (typeof dict === 'string'){
      var dict = dict.split('');
    } else if (!(dict instanceof Array || !dict.length)){
        return false;
    }
    var flags = caseSensitive ? 'g' : 'gi';
    var idx = -1;
    var count, result;
    result = !dict.some(function(v, i){
        count = (str.match(new RegExp(v + '',flags))||[]).length;
        return ((count === 1) && (idx<0)) ? (idx = i, false) : (!count ? false : true);
    });
    return (result && (idx>-1))? idx : false;
}
var changeStringFromRules = [];
var changeStringToRules = [];
function pushRules(thisBtn){
var frm = thisBtn.parentElement;
    var w1 = frm.inputw1.value;
    var w2 = frm.inputw2.value;
    var i1 = determineType(w1, neterminal, true);
    var i2 = determineType(w2, neterminal, true);
    var rt = (i2 !==false) ? 'type2' : ((i1!==false)? 'type1' :  '');
    changeStringFromRules.push(w1);
    changeStringToRules.push(w2);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = w1+'-->'+w2 +' '+ rt;
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
    var removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
    removeBtn.type = "button";
    removeBtn.value = "remove";
    removeBtn.onclick = remove;
    li.appendChild(removeBtn);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);

}
function remove(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    el.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
    <div class="terminal">
       <div id="terminal"></div>
       <div id="newTerminal"></div>
       <div class="addTerminal">
          <form>
            <input id ="inputAdd" type="text">
            <input type="button" value="add" onclick="pushTerminal()">
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="neterminal">
        <div id="neterminal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="addRules">
    <form>
        <label>w1:</label><input name="inputw1" type="text"><label> --> w2:</label><input name="inputw2" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="pushRules(this)">
    </form>
     <div class="container_rules">
        <ui id="list"></ui>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В чем отличие данного вопроса от дубликата? Если конечно отличие есть.

Comment: 1) добавлена проверка на единственность добавления символа, которая не работает.  2) в дубликате проверяется только 2 условия, и там они по-другому заданы